# Forms Authentication cookie not expiring

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

I am trying to implement a very basic Asp.net forms authentication mechanism for a MVC site. The problem I am getting is that my authentication cookie is being set to expire after one year whereas I don't want it to expire after such a long time. Here is some of my code:

**web.config**

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2" />
</authentication>
```

**controller**

```
...
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false);
...
```

I have found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17961503/1140783) (this question is similar but in my case timeout never occurs) but is this the only way to make the cookie expire or am I doing something wrong here?

When I view the cookie it is set to expire after one year even though it should expire after a couple of minutes, why?

What I want is somehow the user gets logged out after some time and I thought setting expiration in `forms` tag would do the job?

Comment: can you post your web.config? specifically the <membership> tag

Comment: I don't have a membership provider in the config

Comment: is that a required thing?

Comment: Yes, I believe there should be. You can try by adding a template MVC starter project that already has Authorization/Membership built in and see how they it's done.

Comment: Well I don't have any membership/roles tables in the db. Also db has its own user table so I just want to use this and get plain authentication without authorization stuff. I know the starter project works out of the box but I don't have a db like that in my project. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Almost a month, 100 views and no answers after I have found a solution.

First, the timeout specified in the `web.config` works only when the cookie is set as persistent i.e. a persistent cookie can also expire. Initially I wrongly assumed that a persistent cookie can not expire. In fact, my original code would have worked if I had always set the cookie to persistent.

Secondly, I believe there is no need for a membership provider to make Forms Authentication work as suggested in the comments above.

Here is how I now create a Authentication cookie:

```
HttpCookie authCookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(username, isPersistent);
if (!isPersistent)
{
    //this is because if it was not set then it got 
    //automatically set to expire next year even if 
    //the cookie was not set as persistent
    authCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15);
}

Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
```

Please let me know if there is any alternate to this?

Comment: Seems like this would work, but what happens if we have slidingExpiration set to `true`?

Comment: I have my persistence set to true and expiration for 30 minutes yet 18 hours later, cookie is still valid.

Comment: @DanielJackson Not sure, I did this back in 2013 and not tried it again since then. Maybe there was a bug with the persistent cookies which got fixed later on?