# Avoid time out issue in Forms Authentication in mvc2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my solution i have Forms Authentication. In my application when user login working it is suddenly log out. so many issues occuring. i change the timeout minutes in configuration like the following. but no hope..

**Web.config**

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880"></forms>
</authentication>
```

**Account Models:**

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, createPersistentCookie);
```

Here i use false method like

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, createPersistentCookie,false);
```

It is showing line error

```
overload methods (String, bool string) like that..
```

please give me ideas about this?

Comment: Suggest looking at my answer to see if it is the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989749/timeout-not-working-in-asp-net-mvc-formsauthentication/17961503#17961503

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create persistent cookies in asp.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140341/how-to-create-persistent-cookies-in-asp-net)

Comment: No, my requirement is different from that.