# Authorizing for multiple websites

Tags: asp.net, session-variables, portal

I have a single solution with multiple Asp.Net projects inside. I would like to Authorize the user in one Project and then allow the credentials to automatically flow into the other projects when the user is redirected to them. Sending credentials via Query String or storing session in SQL Server is not an option. Any ideas ?

Comment: The phrase you're looking for is [Single Sign On](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on)

Comment: Cookies might do the work for you. ASP.NET already has nice login cookies : See [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationticket(v=vs.90).aspx) and [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454616/asp-net-cookies-authentication-and-session-timeouts)

Comment: @freefaller - TY Started googling for Single Sign On.
Sifu - Trying your links now